# Update ddl from existing entity Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I started to use **Jhipster**. I have existing entity in

> com.company.project_name.module_name.MyCastomEntity

which I created manually.

I don't want to use jhipster command

```
yo jhipster:entity MyCustomEntity
```

How to update ddl using  existing entity after manual change(entity creation/updating/deletion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure database properties in your `pom.xml` and use `./mvnw liquibase:diff` to generate a Liquibase migration file that you will store in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog` directory and refer to it from `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml`

This is documented on [JHipster web site](https://jhipster.github.io/development/#database-updates-with-the-maven-liquibasediff-goal)